# Retrofit: Why READ permissions are required if user is allowed to pick the file without permissions?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In android apps, without any explicit permissions, I can pick an image and display using Glide or any other image loading library. This means that the app can read the chosen file. If so, why is it required while uploading it using Retrofit ?

I have seen many examples converting the chosen files path to real path before uploading and it is working well for me. But just wondering why it is really required to have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if app can read the chosen image?

Comment: The app can read the choosen file indeed. But the app will not try to convert the obtained content scheme to a 'real path'. If you do such nasty things than stop doing so.

Comment: @blackapps Do you mean it's bad to convert to real path and upload ? What is the recommended way of uploading without converting to the real path. Any examples you can point me out ?

Comment: Use the uri and open an input stream for it. Read the bytes from the stream. If you then wanna upload the bytes or make a drawing of them is up to you.

Comment: @blackapps okay, I got the idea. gonna try it. Thanks

Comment: Hi @blackapps as per your suggestion, implemented using input stream and indeed it doesn't need the explicit permissions anymore. Ref: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196 Thanks